# PayPal payment not recording transaction If I close browser

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I've enabled PDT, AUTO return, IPN, sent notify_url, success and return_url.

Even with the above set of I make a payment and it's successful, if the user closes the browser before being redirected to my site the payment isn't recorded.

I read IPN should resolve this and I can see the IPN history in my sandbox account but I don't know what causing the payment not to be recorded if the browser is closed before the user is redirected back to my site?

Comment: sounds like it is how your website is implemented. Your server needs to record the payment during the IPN callback but it sounds like it is recording it on the page the user is redirected to

Comment: When you say "record the payment", what do you mean? Is there a particular value I need to set? At present I use the thank you URL as the IPN page as well so if the payment is successful it displays thank you or if it's a payment already processed then it redirects to a decline page.

Comment: well, what do YOU mean by "payment not recorded"?  If paypal shows it as paid, it is paid. If not, then it didn't complete

Comment: By that I mean in on PayPal's website when i make a payment, if it's authorised it asks me to wait to be redirected. I deliberately close my browser and the successful payment is not recorded i.e. the details are NOT saved to my database. IF I leave the browser open at the same stage then the payment is recorded (so the user is redirected back to a thank you page)